# Can not use recursive table (WITH clause) more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
WITH sciezka AS
(
    (something)
)
SELECT TOP 1 @ciag= miasta FROM sciezka WHERE ID_konca=@koniec;
SELECT TOP 1 @ciag2= odleglosci FROM sciezka WHERE ID_konca=@koniec;
```

It says that 'sciezka' and 'odleglosci' is invalid name, in second command, but it is valid in first command. Why I can not use table 'sciezka' more than once?

Comment: Because that's how CTE's work - they're defined and used for just the one statement following the definition ....

Comment: can I use anything similar in order to use this table more times?

Comment: If you need it more than once - maybe consider making this a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CTE (defined in a `with`) is attached to only one `select`.  You can use a temporary table or table variable.

In your case, you can do:

```
WITH sciezka AS
(
    (something)
)
SELECT TOP 1 @ciag= miasta, @ciag2= odleglosci 
FROM sciezka
WHERE ID_konca=@koniec;
```